# Is there a good rails gem to output the view equivalent of rake routes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What I'm looking for is a gem that could output a complete webpage version of each view a rails app has.

I realize I might not have correctly worded this. What I mean is I would like to see each route that has html output, but what the view actually looks like, not just a line saying what the view is.

Answer (score 1):

In development (rails 4.x) you can simply go to any non-existent page and it will return all of the routes.

Example Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23115266/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-27%20at%209.21.03%20AM.png

Answer (score 0):

The sextant gem allows you to see all your application's views in development by navigating to the /rails/routes URL.

https://github.com/schneems/sextant

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you want a listing of view templates. Not sure there is a gem that can do this, but you could easily do it yourself with the following:

```
module ShowViewsHelper

  def all_views_from_path(path)
    helpers = Array(path).flat_map do |_path|
      extract = /^#{Regexp.quote(_path.to_s)}\/?(.*)_.erb$/
      names = Dir["#{_path}/**/*.erb"].map { |file| file.sub(extract, '\1') }
      names.sort!
    end
    helpers.uniq!
    helpers
  end

end
```

create a template somewhere with the following:

```
  <ul>
  <% all_views_from_path("app/views").each do |v| %>
    <li><%= v %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
```